# Container size not adjusting and items being hidden behind things

Tags: javascript, html, css, visual-studio-code

I have 2 containers, one to register an  account and one to login to an account. The issue is with the register account container. The top and bottoms parts of the inside of the container are being cutoff. I've tried to adjust multiple off the containers themselves and of other css things, but nothing is making it so that all of the items in the container are being shown at once like for the login container.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  document.getElementById('personnelBtn').classList.add('selected');
};

function myMenuFunction() {
  var i = document.getElementById("navMenu");
  if (i.className === "nav-menu") {
    i.className += " responsive";
  } else {
    i.className = "nav-menu";
  }
}

var a = document.getElementById("loginBtn");
var b = document.getElementById("registerBtn");
var x = document.getElementById("login");
var y = document.getElementById("register");

function login() {
  x.style.left = "4px";
  y.style.right = "-520px";
  a.className += " white-btn";
  b.className = "btn";
  x.style.opacity = 1;
  y.style.opacity = 0;
}

function register() {
  x.style.left = "-510px";
  y.style.right = "5px";
  a.className = "btn";
  b.className += " white-btn";
  x.style.opacity = 0;
  y.style.opacity = 1;
}

function selectAccount(type) {
  console.log("Selected account type: " + type);
  document.getElementById('personnelBtn').classList.remove('selected');
  document.getElementById('entrepriseBtn').classList.remove('selected');
  document.getElementById(type + 'Btn').classList.add('selected');

  var firstNameInput = document.getElementById('firstNameInput');
  var lastNameInput = document.getElementById('lastNameInput');
  var companyNameInput = document.getElementById('companyNameInput');

  if (type === 'personnel') {
    firstNameInput.style.display = 'block';
    lastNameInput.style.display = 'block';
    companyNameInput.style.display = 'none';
  } else if (type === 'entreprise') {
    firstNameInput.style.display = 'none';
    lastNameInput.style.display = 'none';
    companyNameInput.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```css
/* POPPINS FONT */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&display=swap');
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  min-height: 110vh;
  background: rgba(39, 39, 39, 0.4);
}

.nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(39, 39, 39, 0.6), transparent);
  z-index: 100;
}

.nav-logo p {
  color: white;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.nav-menu ul {
  display: flex;
}

.nav-menu ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav-menu ul li .link {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  margin: 0 25px;
}

.link:hover,
.active {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #fff;
}

.nav-button .btn {
  width: 130px;
  height: 40px;
  font-weight: 500;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4);
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s ease;
}

.btn:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

#registerBtn {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.btn.white-btn {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.btn.btn.white-btn:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
}

.nav-menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.form-box {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 512px;
  height: 420px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}

.login-container,
.register-container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 20px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  z-index: 3;
}

.login-container {
  left: 4px;
  height: auto;
}

.register-container {
  right: -520px;
  height: auto;
  /* Adjusted height to auto */
  max-height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  /* Added max-height */
  overflow-y: auto;
  /* Added overflow-y */
}

.top span {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: small;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.top span a {
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

header {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px 0 30px 0;
}

.two-forms {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.input-field {
  font-size: 15px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
  color: #fff;
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 10px 0 45px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  outline: none;
  transition: .2s ease;
}

.input-field:hover,
.input-field:focus {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
}

::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #fff;
}

.input-box i {
  position: relative;
  top: -35px;
  left: 17px;
  color: #fff;
}

.submit {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: black;
  height: 45px;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 30px;
  outline: none;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.submit:hover {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  box-shadow: 1px 5px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.two-col {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: small;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.two-col .one {
  display: flex;
  gap: 5px;
}

.two label a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
}

.two label a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 786px) {
  .nav-button {
    display: none;
  }
  .nav-menu.responsive {
    top: 100px;
  }
  .nav-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: -800px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    transition: .3s;
  }
  .nav-menu ul {
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .nav-menu-btn {
    display: block;
  }
  .nav-menu-btn i {
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 10px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    border-radius: 50%;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: .3s;
  }
  .nav-menu-btn i:hover {
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 540px) {
  .wrapper {
    min-height: 100vh;
  }
  .form-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 500px;
  }
  .register-container,
  .login-container {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0 20px;
  }
  .register-container .two-forms {
    flex-direction: column;
    gap: 0;
  }
}

.back-video {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  z-index: -1;
  -o-filter: blur(15px);
  filter: blur(15px);
}

.account-type {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.account-btn {
  width: 180px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 0 20px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  color: #000;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease;
}

.account-btn.selected {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
}

#companyNameInput {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link href='https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css' rel='stylesheet'>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="inscriptionstyle.css">
  <title>Connexion & Inscription</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <video id="video1" src="Background Videos\Background_Video_Connection.mp4" autoplay muted loop plays-inline class="back-video"></video>
    <nav class="nav">
      <div class="nav-logo">
        <p>Clipper Link MTL .</p>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-menu" id="navMenu">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">Acceuil</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">À propos</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link">Contact</a></li>
          <li><a href="#" class="link active">Connexion/Inscription</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-button">
        <button class="btn white-btn" id="loginBtn" onclick="login()">Connexion</button>
        <button class="btn" id="registerBtn" onclick="register()">Inscription</button>
      </div>
      <div class="nav-menu-btn">
        <i class="bx bx-menu" onclick="myMenuFunction()"></i>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!----------------------------- Form box ----------------------------------->
    <div class="form-box">

      <!------------------- login form -------------------------->
      <div class="login-container" id="login">
        <div class="top">
          <span>Pas de compte? <a href="#" onclick="register()">Inscription</a></span>
          <header>Connexion</header>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
          <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Courriel">
          <i class="bx bx-user"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
          <input type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Mot de passe">
          <i class="bx bx-lock-alt"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="input-box">
          <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Connecter">
        </div>
        <div class="two-col">
          <div class="one">
            <input type="checkbox" id="login-check">
            <label for="login-check"> Rapelle toi de moi</label>
          </div>
          <div class="two">
            <label><a href="#">Mot de passe oublié?</a></lzabel>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!------------------- registration form -------------------------->
        <div class="register-container" id="register">
            <div class="top">
                <span>T'a déjà un compte? <a href="#" onclick="login()">Connecte toi</a></span>
                <header>Inscription</header>
                <div class="account-type">
                    <button class="account-btn" id="personnelBtn" onclick="selectAccount('personnel')">Personnel</button>
                    <button class="account-btn" id="entrepriseBtn" onclick="selectAccount('entreprise')">Entreprise</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="two-forms">
                <div class="input-box" id="firstNameInput">
                    <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Prénom">
                    <i class="bx bx-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box" id="lastNameInput">
                    <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Nom de famille">
                    <i class="bx bx-user"></i>
                </div>
                <div class="input-box" id="companyNameInput" style="display: none;">
                    <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Nom de l'entreprise">
                    <i class="bx bx-building"></i>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="text" class="input-field" placeholder="Courriel">
                <i class="bx bx-envelope"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="password" class="input-field" placeholder="Mot de passe">
                <i class="bx bx-lock-alt"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="input-box">
                <input type="submit" class="submit" value="Inscrire">
            </div>
            <div class="two-col">
                <div class="one">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="register-check">
                    <label for="register-check"> Rapelle toi de moi</label>
          </div>
          <div class="two">
            <label><a href="#">Terms & conditions</a></label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="inscription.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

As stated, ive tried adjusting the parameters of multiple css things.

Comment: the `.form-box` wrapper is only 420px in height so it's not enough for the register form

Comment: what does this have to do with VS Code? did you read its tag usage guidance?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your form-box css as you have given height 420px which is not enough for the form. Try below code I have changed the height to 600px you can change it according to your need.

```
.form-box {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 512px;
  height: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}
```